# Дублирование материалов с сайта в соц.сети

Tags: joomla, соцсети

Ребят, передо мной стоит задача сделать так, чтоб при публикации материала на сайте (joomla 1.5), этот же материал появлялся в соцсетях (VK, OK, FB, Мой мир, Twitter) в соответствующие группы/каналы. Подскажите какие способы существуют для реализации этой задачи? Хабр, вроде как, делает так же. Моментально материал появляется в группе ВК и на самом хабре.

Answer (score 4):

Читайте API.

- [VK](http://vk.com/page2369267)
- [FB](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/)
- [OK](http://dev.odnoklassniki.ru/wiki/display/ok/Odnoklassniki+Rest+API)
- [MM](http://api.mail.ru/)
- [TW](https://dev.twitter.com/)

Всё делается на нём. Почти в каждом API соцсети присутствуют методы типа wallPost(контент). Но везде различается и API. Универсального метода нет, но вы можете создать свои, передавая контент через них.

---

OFFTOP:
Не стоит просто слепо пихать всё что добавляете в соцсети. Используйте очередь неотправленных постов. Управляйте cron'ом так, чтобы проверялась очередь и по определённому признаку (количество просмотров, новизна и пр.) добавлялась через промежуток времени. Придумайте концепцию чтобы пользователи постоянно получали информацию, а не только когда Вы напишите статью или пр. Хабр выезжает за счёт того, что статьи пишут сами пользователи и они появляются  иднём и ночью.

Comment: 100 баллов тебе в подарок - не за ответ - за совет